# Execute ssm.send_command to EC2 from Lambda. IAM problems

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I have problems with execution command on Windows machine from Lambda function using ssm.send_command in Python. This Lambda functions should execute simple command on windows machine:

```
import boto3
ssm = boto3.client('ssm')
region = 'us-east-1'
instances = ['i-XXXXXXXXXXXXX']

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = ssm.send_command(
        InstanceIds=instances,
        DocumentName='AWS-RunPowerShellScript',
        DocumentVersion='$DEFAULT',
        DocumentHash='2142e42a19e0955cc09e43600bf2e633df1917b69d2be9693737dfd62e0fdf61',
        DocumentHashType='Sha256',
        TimeoutSeconds=123,
        Comment='string',
        Parameters={
            'commands': [
#                'query user'
                'mkdir test-dir'
            ]
        },
        MaxErrors='1',
        CloudWatchOutputConfig={
            'CloudWatchLogGroupName': 'WindowsLogs',
            'CloudWatchOutputEnabled': True
        }
    )
    print response
```

Execution role for this L-functions is

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:SendCommand"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ssm:*:*:document/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:SendCommand"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Also I added policies:

`AmazonEC2FullAccess`

`AmazonEC2RoleforSSM`

`AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore`

`CloudWatchLogsFullAccess`

`AmazonSSMFullAccess`

`AmazonSSMAutomationRole`

`AmazonSSMMaintenanceWindowRole`

For EC2 no roles were assigned

Problem: I don't see that folder "test-dir' was created on Windows server. Please can you help me to determine what is missing, or how can I configure Lambda function for executing command and send results to CloudWatch.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the `AmazonSSMFullAccess` policy to the instance, otherwise it won't work.
Make sure to restart the instance after the change.

If that doesn't work:

- Add `try` and `except` blocks to your code to check what's the error.
- Check that you have the **SSMAgent** installed on your instance (connect to it, open PowerShell and execute `Restart-Service AmazonSSMAgent`).

Comment: This works, but please be aware of the significant security implications. Any user with SSM command access can now read and put to ALL of your s3 buckets, among other issues: https://cloudonaut.io/aws-ssm-is-a-trojan-horse-fix-it-now/ . Use `AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore` instead if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @fsinis90 for your recommendations.

I tried them and also I added such policies to my instance's role:

- AWSHealthFullAccess
- AmazonEC2RoleforSSM
- AWSConfigUserAccess
- AmazonSSMFullAccess
- CloudWatchReadOnlyAccess

And it helps.